# Yarn Installation not brings Vue files

Tags: vue.js, yarn-lock.json

As a newbie, i am trying to properly install yarn via VsCode terminal, and having an issue;
I use

> yarn add -g @vue/cli

command to install, after installation i am still not able to use vue ui command(throws: the term ‘vue’ is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet…’), so it made me think of the vue.cmd not installed in my system, then i check my **npm directory**, i can see 3 different yarn files, but no **vue** files at all..

I have been using npm before and already uninstalled before yarn installation, with following command:

> npm uninstall -g @vue/cli

After uninstalling npm, the vue files in npm directory are gone, as expected.
Is there any other step that I should take to install vue.cmd files(if its necessary)?
Maybe i should not have to uninstall npm, becacuse npm installation brings vue files into my system?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

```sh
yarn add -g @vue/cli
```

Use this command:

```sh
yarn global add @vue/cli
```

Note: If you are on windows you have to use `CMD` to run `vue cli` commands. As by default `PowerShell` doesn't allow to run packages that were installed globally via `npm` or `yarn`. You may need to disable `PowerShell` security to use that package in `PowerShell`. But I recommend you to use `cmd` to use the package after installation. But still, you can install the package via `PowerShell`.

Comment: I think that was the problem, powershell does not allow me to run packages i think. (npm installation never be a problem,). I might be disable security shield on PowerShell for npm but for yarn somehow. This solved my problem, thank you.